# Show $\sum^{\infty}_0q^k$ converges with integral test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I am trying to show that the series $$\sum^{\infty}_0q^k$$ converges when $q<1$ using the integral test, assuming $q>0$.

The series is given by function $f(x)=q^x$ which is positive and decreasing when $k<0$. The series can be written as an improper integral $$\sum^\infty_0q^k=\int^\infty_0 q^xdx$$
and if the improper integral converges, the series converges by the integral test.

With substitution $u=x\ln q$ and $du=\ln q\,dx$ where the bounds stay the same since $0\ln q =0$ and $\infty\ln q = \infty$,
$$\int^{\infty}_0 q^xdx=\int^{\infty}_0 e^{x\ln q}dx=\frac{1}{\ln q}\int^{\infty}_0 e^udu=\frac{1}{\ln q}\Biggr|^{\infty}_0 e^u.$$

However, now 
$$\frac{1}{\ln q}\Biggr|^{\infty}_0 e^u=\frac{1}{\ln q}(e^{\infty}-1)$$
which converges. What is wrong with my proof?

Comment: In your substitution, because $0<q<1$, $\log q <0$, so your range of integration should be $(-\infty,0]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $q \in (0,1)$ implies that $\log(q)\in (-\infty,0)$, so the limit after the substitution is wrong.

Comment: That is, $\int_0^\infty e^{x\ln q}dx$ becomes $\frac{1}{\ln q}\int_0^{-\infty}e^u du$

Comment: @GEdgar Yes! ${}$

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $u=x\log q$, the integration bounds become $\dfrac 0{\log q}$ and $\dfrac\infty{\log q}$. But mind the sign of $\log q$ !

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that $+\infty\ln q=-\infty$ since $\ln q<0.$